# Communication between war files using HttpClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, restlet

I have two war files, they both located on the same server.
I want to use some API war1 presents in war2.
I have been told to use Apache's HttpClient but I'm not sure how, I would like a push in the right direction.

suppose war1 is `api.common-1.53.46.20150305-1042.war` and I want to call a method `getFormatedDate()` in the class `DateFormatter` under the packege `com.bo.api.common.utilities`

If you have a solution using Restlet, it will suffice as well. As for now I'm in the beginning of my project.

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing WARs with JARs. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "approach a method", so I'm assuming you mean to say "call a method"

Comment: I'm not confusing jars with wars. I know how to call a method that is in a jar (I set a dependency).
Yes, I meant "call a method" :)

Comment: Do you mean through a webservice? Are these WARs deployed on separate containers (e.g. Tomcat)?

Comment: yes, through a webservice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call method directly but you need to export something from the war with HTTP and call it from the other one.

I don't know which technology you use for the first war (servlet directly, a framework above like Restlet, Spring MVC, JAX-RS frameworks, ...) but you need to expose your method through an HTTP method on a dedicated URI.

Then code like below can be used to call it from the second war:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://<same-domain>/war2-rootpath/dateformatter");
Representation repr = cr.put(new StringRepresentation(...));
StringRepresentation sRepr = new StringRepresentation(repr);
String returnedText = sRepr.getText();
```

My code is a bit generic since your question is a bit vague ;-)

**Edited**

I think that you can a path like `/dates` with a method `POST`. The latter would accept a payload that contains the data as long (time value) and would return the formatted date as a string. The corresponding server resource would be something like that:

```
public class DateFormatterServerResource extends ServerResource {
    @Post
    public String formatDate(long time) {
        return DateFormatter.getFormatedDate(new Date(time));
    }
}
```

This server resource would be attach of the router of your application as described below:

```
Router router = (...)
router.attach("/dates", DateFormatterServerResource.class);
```

Hope it helps you anyway.
Thierry

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for.
I use `Restlet`.
How do I expose my method?

Comment: I edited my answer to add the correspond server resource that exposes your method.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't classify webservices as a beginner's concept, so there's probably a bit of research you'll want to do before just diving in and trying to code this. However, here's a push in the right direction like you asked for: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue using **`Restlet`**.

I wrapped the class I want to expose as a `Restlet` resource (by this he is serving as the server).

On the other side I use `ClientResource` to retrieve (by `Get` in my case) the data I need.

Server side:

```
@Get
public JSONObject getIp(JsonRepresentation j) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject request = j.getJsonObject();
    . . .
}
```

Client side:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://localhost:8111/");
Representation repr = cr.get();
. . .
```